# Open Shift additional port

Tags: openshift

I'm using tomcat 7 at openShift gear. I'm trying to deploy application which is creatting rmiserver. Unfortunetly application couldnt start because all ports I've tried to use was already in use. Is it anyway to check (or somehow book one port for me) which port I can use for my RMI ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasnt able to get answer to my question anywhere, also OPenShift support didnt reponse at all. I've moved to Jelastic ;)